# How to install UDK on a Mac?

Tags: iphone, ios, unreal-development-kit

Hi I have recently been told that UDK is a great game engine and can run on iPhone. But UDK can only be used on a PC right? I don't have a PC and the same person who recommended UDK said that it was possible to make UDK games on a mac but you have to download something else first? Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks :)

Comment: Or just run Windows in a VM/Boot Camp...

Comment: On a sufficiently powerful Mac, a VM is fine (and kind of cool, because you can just switch between OS X and Windows with a simple flick gesture). If you don't have that, you can just use Boot Camp and reboot to Windows when you want to do UDK development.

Comment: hmm... Would this work on a MacBook air?

Comment: yes, it works on all post-leopard macs. You need a copy of windows to do it, but them go to utilities->boot camp

Comment: Thanks :) how do I install VM? just google it?

Answer (score 2):

OP you do not want to run UDK on a macbook air, you need an iMac, macbook pro with dedicated gpu, a gaming pc or laptop, or a workstation like a mac pro, UDK is extremely demanding software and it will not be responsive enough on slower hardware and may have other problems on the air's integrated graphics - while some UE3 games may run playably on integrated graphics hardware like the air's, developing them is quite another thing and is much more taxing.

Answer (score 0):

UDK, or Unreal Development Kit, is for making games, and does not run on an iPhone, and will not run on a mac to my knowledge.  You must have heard about UE3, or Unreal Engine 3, will run on an iPhone, Mac, or Linux computer.  However, it is built into games, i.e. Infinity Blade on the iPhone, or UE3 powered games on a Mac.  UDK will not run on a Mac, to my knowledge, except under VMWare, Parallels, or Boot Camp.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how good it will run on your system, but the best thing to do would be simply running windows virtually (making ios a host operating system and windows a guest). That way you would imitate windows and you could easily install UDK. I don't have a mac so I don't know excatly, but I think that BootCamp is a good place to start looking for virtual machines software.